# Как отключить службу во время входящего звонка?

Tags: android

какой кусок кода нужно вставить, чтобы программа (или игра) остановилась, когда звонят

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получать оповещение о входящем звонке, вам нужно переопределить [PhoneStateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) и добавить его к TelephonyManager c помощью [TelephonyManager.listen()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int)):

```
manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.listen(listener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Если нужен телефонный номер, запросите пермишен:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```